# Revoke / invalidate Mac app signed with Developer ID

Tags: macos, certificate

I used to distribute a Mac app signed with Developer ID internally. Now I sell this app through the Mac App Store. Is there any way to invalidate the old Developer ID signature, or prevent the old app from running? I'd like to stop the old version from being used, or at least stop it from being redistributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your internal app has no way to update itself them you really can't do much.

What you can do is revoke your certificate and release a new version of your app on the Mac App Store. This still won't prevent the already installed app from running. Just that newer installs can be prohibited.

In your Mac app store version of the app make sure you have some upgrade logic. I.e., if the user has the older app and the newer one then the newer one should delete the older app.

I hope it helps.